# Reorder gps trajectories for similarity measures

Tags: python, gps, gis, similarity

I have three GPS trajectories given as a set of x and y coordinates (transformed from WSG84). I applied similaritymeasures.area_between_two_curves() from the similaritymeasures python package and found that the area is calculated point by point. I was wondering if there is a way to first find common subparts to only compare them. Also I want to ignore the order of the points as you see that the red and the green trajectory is very similar but with a different direction/ order of the points.

[image: Trajectories]

Comment: this doesn't seem specific to GPS, specifically algorithms described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence would seem reasonable.  I'd just try twice, once to look for forward and second time for reverse matches.  algorithm choice would depend a lot on lengths of data and number of traces you want to compare.  if they are longer than a few hundred points it would likely be worth resampling at lower frequency for an initial match